# Problems with case statements in Leaflet's pointToLayer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to create a layer that has different types of business (separated by the keyword 'code' (1,2,3, etc) properties in the geojson file) but when it executes the pointToLayer below I get an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'feature' of undefined. What am i doing wrong?

```
var allbusinesses = L.geoJson(data, {
  style: allBusinessesStyle,
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    switch (feature.properties.code) {
      case "1":
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
        color: "#000"
      });
      ...
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't being caused by the `onEachFeature` function because as far as i can see, your switch is ok and you're not setting a property as the error you're getting suggests...

Comment: Yeah, sounds like you just need to do normal debugging - replace the contents of your function with just a simple `return` - does it work then? etc.

Comment: iH8 and Steve, thank you both for you help. The problem was the lack of a default in the switch statement, see here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180038/problems-with-case-statements-in-leaflets-pointtolayer/180264#180264